# Unable to download large data using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download, encodeuricomponent

I have a large data in form of JSON object in the javascript. I have converted it into the string using JSON.stringify(). Now my use case is to provide this large string in a text file to the user. So for this i have written below code.

**HTML code**

```
  <button id='text_feed' type="submit">Generate ION Feed</button>

  <a href="data:attachment/txt" id="textLink" download="feed.txt"></a>
```

**Javascript code**

```
 var text = //huge string  

 $("#text_feed").click(function() {
        _generateFeed(text);
 });

 var _generateFeed = function(text) {
    //some code here
    $("#textLink").attr("href",
                          "data:attachment/txt," + encodeURIComponent(text))  [0].click();
    });
 };
```

**Problem**: When the string length is small , i am able to download the data .
But when the string length goes higher (> 10^5) , my page crashes.
This occurred because "encodeUriComponet(text)" is not able to encode large 
data.

I also tried `window.open("data:attachment/txt," + encodeURIComponent(text));` 
But again my page got crashed because of the same reason that encodeURIComponet was unable to encode such a large string.

**Another approach:** I was also thinking of writing the data into a file using HTML5 File write API , but it has support only in Chrome web browser , but i need to make this work for atleast firefox and chrome both.

**Use Case**
I don't want to do multiple downloads by breaking the data, as i need to have data in a single file in the end.

And my target is to support string of aprroximately 10^6 length. Can anyone help me how to download/write this amount of data into a single file.

Comment: How about  `URL.createObjectURL (new Blob(text, {type : 'text/plain'}));` - does that work?

Comment: @RGraham Agreed, try the [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob)!

Comment: [Here’s a demo of that](http://jsfiddle.net/efLfqp3f/). Blob compiles a megabyte of text like it’s nothing.

Comment: @RGraham and Xufox thanks.
 It works for me :)

Comment: Except don't forget to check the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) of URL and createObjectURL.

Comment: @user2509908 Don't worry, it's got better support than the `[download]` attribute itself :) @user3704217 you should leave an answer with the code to demonstrate how you solved it in the context of the problem!

Comment: @RGraham Fair enough. I didn't mean to undermine your answer. Just thought worth noting that many of these techniques are not as compatible as we think. You are correct, however. I can delete my comments if you wish :)

Comment: Not at all! That's not what I was getting at, just pointing out that if the `[download]` attribute it being used, that will most likely be the compatibility bottleneck :) Your comment is certainly valid!

Comment: I solved it as below.
`var _generateFeed = function(text) {
    /*some code here*/
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob(
                [text],
                {type:'text/plain'}
            )
        );
    $("#textLink").attr("href",url)[0].click();
 };`

Comment: wich one is your server? maybe a expressjs server?? It has a limit to json files..

Comment: @ankur37 This question should be closed if you found a solution. There's no need for it to appear on the unanswered list.

Comment: "...must be released by calling URL.revokeObjectURL() when you no longer need them. Browsers will release these automatically when the document is unloaded; however, for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them, you should do so." 

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL )

Comment: @Xufox, the demo do not work for me. Improve it by add download attribute to <a> element. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efLfqp3f/8/)

Answer (score 1):

[From the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167326/unable-to-download-large-data-using-javascript#comment48446606_30167326):

> I solved it as below.
>
> ```
> var _generateFeed = function(text) {
>     /*some code here*/
>     var url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [text], {type:'text/plain'} ) );
>     $("#textLink").attr("href",url)[0].click();
> };
> ```

Notes:

- [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is compatible with modern browsers and IE10+, but it is an unstable, experimental technology.
- Objects created using URL.createObjectURL() "*must be released by calling [URL.revokeObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) when you no longer need them.*" - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Notes)