# Large Csv File export with Blazor? (The JSON value of length n is too large and not supported.)

Tags: export, blazor, blazor-server-side

Firstly to export my csv export I used this method with JSInterop logic. And It works for small size file.

await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync(
        "FileSaveAs",
        fileName,
        noteContent
    );

I tried to download large size file .While InvokeAsync I got an error *"The JSON value of length 475458916 is too large and not supported.'*

SaveFile.js is like below:

```
function FileSaveAs(filename, fileContent) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContent)
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);}
```

My file size can be 2GBs, 1GBs. I researched blazor side for export operation But I only saw jsinterop example(my first sample) .

Note:I m also Using Devexpress Blazor for UI things.

Comment: You can try to create Blob like this [example-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167326/unable-to-download-large-data-using-javascript). Hope it helps.

Comment: But before coming javascript side, it blows at 
 await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
        "FileSaveAs",
        fileName,
        noteContent
    );

Comment: I would generate the link to point to an endpoint on the server that downloads the file rather than trying to push it all the way to the client, encode it as a blob then save it

Comment: You mean like post download??@MisterMagoo

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "like post download". I mean generate a link like `<a href='/downloads/h373hw' download='your file.csv'>` and have an endpoint on the server at `/downloads` that serves up the CSV data. At the moment, you are trying to send all the data from the server to the client, encoding it as a data URI and putting the entire file into the DOM just to then tell the browser to download it, which is not practical.